# Variable to keep track of contentView, then call inalidateOptionsMenu()

Tags: android, android-actionbar, setcontentview

My main goal is to refresh the options menu depending on what layout is current in the Activity.  I don't want the buttons on my Action Bar when R.layout.preweb is active, but when setContentView is changed to R.layout.main becomes active, invalidateOptionsMenu and inflate.  Here's what I have now:

```
private int mViewMode;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return mViewMode == 2;
}
```

And throughout my activity, in random methods, I have this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.preweb);
mViewMode = 1;

//or somewhere else

setContentView(R.layout.main);
mViewMode = 2;
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

So basically, whenever mViewMode is set to 2, invalidateOptionsMenu is called and then onCreateOptionsMenu should retrigger, and being mViewMode now equals 2, I should then inflate.  But nothing is happening - it never inflates.

What's up here?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On invalidating menu using [`invalidateOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu()), method [`onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)) will be called, not [`onCreateOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)). So you need to override this method, and you need to write code to show menu item or hide menu item.

For example

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    if (mViewMode == 2) {
        // Need to show menu items
        menu.findItem(R.id.menuitem1).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menuitem2).setVisible(true);
    } else {
        // Need to hide menu items
        menu.findItem(R.id.menuitem1).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menuitem2).setVisible(false);
    }      
    return true;
}
```

and [`onCreateOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)) does not gets called when you say [`invalidateOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu()), so no need to return `false` from there. You always need to return `true` from it.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: Well, silly me, I had the wrong method.  Thanks a bunch.